# How do I make my grid items(boxes with content in them) responsive using bootstrap 5?

Tags: grid, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am working on a website that has a filter section and a list of offerings in its main body section.

I want the list of offerings to be setup like how YouTube videos are set up on its homepage. When you change the size the box size changes accordingly while still ensuring that the content looks neat.

```css
.filter{
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px; 
    background-color: pink;
}
.card{
    width: 300px;
    height: 370px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-10">
              <div class="col-md">
                  <div class="filter"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-10">
              <div class="row d-grid gap-3">
                  <div class="p-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 card"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="p-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 card"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="p-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 card"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="p-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 card"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all the boxes have the same widths and heights as the viewport size changes, one way to achieve this with bootstrap 5 is to use the .row-cols-{bp}-* classes, which allows to specify the preferred columns per row for each responsive breakpoint.

One example: [See working example](https://codepen.io/ormasoftchile/pen/VwPJRQp)

In this example, for responsive breakpoints there can be 1, 2 or 4 columns.

If like youtube you'd need to keep a fixed aspect ratio for each card's width/height, there is the .ratio family of classes.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-auto g-4">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="ratio ratio-4x3 card bg-primary"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="ratio ratio-4x3 card bg-secondary"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I've chosen the 4x3 aspect ratio for each card.
Please see more info at [Ratios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/#aspect-ratios).